# listRowInsets doesn't work if the List is instantiated with data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

With this simple `List`, the `listRowInsets` modifier works as expected (the color red has no inset in the list row):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Color.red
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the `List` is instantiated with a `data` parameter, `listRowInsets` stops working:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< 1) { _ in
            Color.red
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the content of a list item to have no inset in the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `List` with `ForEach`, like below

```
List {
    ForEach(0 ..< 1) { _ in
        Color.red
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
    }
}
```